# Relevance to increase kettlebell weight

Tags: kettlebell

I'm using kettlebells everyday for a little bit more than 3 months now.
At the beginning I was barely able to do 1 set of 12 with an 8 kg KB.

Now I have the following daily workout:

- Two-hands swing: 5 x 50 with a 24 kg KB
- One-hand swing: 4 x 30 (each side) with a 16 KB
- Two arms deadlift: 3 x 50 with 40 kg (24 + 16)

Given that my main objectives are to fix my postural issues (anterior pelvic tilt (APT) and rounded shoulders), maybe to gain my carrying ability but not to lose weight.
Is it worth it to continue and/or increase weight for swings?

Comment: Why are you trying to "fix" these "postural issues"?  What problem(s) do they cause?

Comment: Mostly pain and unbalances during walk.

Comment: Regarding posture and pain, please see ["Your Back Is Not Out of Alignment"](https://www.painscience.com/articles/structuralism.php).  I'm unsure what you mean by "unbalances during walk".

Answer (score 2):

I applaud your strength increases!  But, I fail to see how kettlebell swings could reduce anterior pelvic tilt or shoulder-rounding.  Actually, I can imagine how KB swings might *exacerbate* both of those postural tendencies.

In general, posture is unconscious.  One of the first steps to changing posture is developing awareness of posture.  As you increase your awareness of your posture, you can change muscular engagement to reinforce the posture that you want.

I have no recommendations for exercises to reduce APT.

To help reduce shoulder-rounding, consider strengthening your back via deadlifts, chin-ups, and bent-over barbell rows.

Comment: If my understanding is correct APT is (among other things) due to weak glutes which are worked in the swings (of course I have an extra attention to my lower back). (Thanks for the applause, I have good genes) Thanks for the new exercises, I have started chin-up (well, chest to bar pull ups) this week.